# How to validate POST request in symfony 5

Tags: php, api, symfony

Currently I'm using this method to validate data coming from a POST request:

```
//src/Controller/UserCreationController.php
//Creates collection
$constraints = new Collection([
    'username' => (new Required(new NotBlank())),
    'password' => (new Required(new NotBlank())),
    'email' => (new Required([new NotBlank(), new Email()])),
    'readAndAgree' => (new Required(new NotBlank())),
    'receiveUpdates' => (new Required(new NotBlank())),
]);

//Creates validator
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$validation = $validator->validate(json_decode($request->getContent(), true), $constraints);

//Check for errors
if(count($validation) > 0) {
    //Return bad fields
    $errorsString = (string) $validation;
    return $this->json($errorsString, 400);
}
```

Is it possible to use [Symfony's validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) and create a custom validator for POST data? (most times not related to a model, so I couldn't find a good example).
The goal is to make the controller's code cleaner, so I'm looking for possibilities in creating a new .yml in */config/validator*, but all examples I can find are related to models and not custom data.

Comment: You could use a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that is a class with only attributes, getters and setters. Then you hydrate your DTO with data from your request and you put validation on its fields.

Comment: Thank you @FlorianHermann I was afraid that this was the case, so my idea of having a custom *yml* declaration inst viable?

Comment: You can do it but i'm afraid not without developing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @FlorianHermann, I ended up coding my own solution, it still not perfect but solves my needs for now.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use DTO you can use form component without connecting it with entity -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html
It's very clean and reusable solution. However there is also a way to do it in your way

```
class someClass {

private $validator;

public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator) {
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

public function yourMethod(array $postData) {
    // you can also create validator like that
    // $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    $constraints = new Assert\Collection([
        'username' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank()
        ],
        'email' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Email()
        ],
        ...
    ]);

    $validationResult = $this->validator->validate($postData, $constraints);
}
}
```

Read more about it in [validating raw values](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html) section.

Comment: Hi @sabat I ended up creating my own solution. I created a bundle that reads the annotation and applies the selected validation (declared in a separated yaml). Thank you!